# To catch the reason of the unique constraint on JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to learn JPA and I have a problem that I stucked in since 2 days.

I have a table named "User" includes id,email,password,username and status.

As you guess email and username columns are unique.

I also have a Class called User something like that :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"username", "email"}))
public class User {    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @Column(name="email", nullable=false)
    private String email;
    @Column(name="password", nullable=false)
    private String password;
    @Column(name="username", nullable=false)
    private String username;
    @Column(name="status", nullable=false)
    private String status;
```

Rest of this class is getters and setters.

I am trying to insert a value by using JPA with Hibernate.

```
    try {
            em = jpaResourceBean.getEMF().createEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            user.setStatus(UserStatus.PENDING.toString());
            em.persist(user);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            logger.info("User " + user.getUsername() + " has been registered");
    // Attention starts
        } catch (XXXXXX) { 
    if (XXXXX.getYYY().equals("ZZZZZ")) logger.info("User name is already exist");
    if (XXXXX.getMMM().equals("LLLLL")) logger.info("Email is already exist");
        } 
    // Attention end
```

All I want to know : How can I understand is the problem with the username constraint or the email unique constraint? While you can check my Attention start and end block, I am sure that you get my point : )

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This does not answer your question, but in your example, there is one constraint on the combination of username and email. You probably want `uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"username"}), @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"email"})}`.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use auto-generated schemas in production, so why not simply set the contraint name in your schema. Then when the exception is generated, you will get the failing constraint name.

```
create table users (
      user varchar2(20) not null,
      email varchar2(20) not null,

      constraint user_uq unique(user),
      constraint email_uq unique(email)
)
```

You might want to have a look in the database before you insert to see if they are already there.. that way you most likely wont get an exception anyway...

Comment: Hi, I would like to say that is what I want. It is no matter who gave the constraint name. It may be mine or it may be auto generated. 
The point is catchin' its name from the code. 
And actually I do not want to look in the database before I insert. Because I don't want to go to the database twice. That's why I want to get constraint name from java Exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
catch(javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException exception) {
    Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> constraintViolations = exception.getConstraintViolations();
...
}
```

Comment: Sadly, in case of a unique constraint violation, you'll get a `PersistenceException`, Bean Validation won't be here.